# How to change speed of a hero animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have made simple hero animation following instructions from [Flutter's website](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations)

It works as described in the instructions but in my case, I would like it to animate much more slowly from the first to the second screen. do anyone know how to change the speed of this animation?

Comment: it depends of the PageRoute transition duration, so you will have to create/implement your own PageRoute

Comment: you may find this solution helpful [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476995/hero-animation-not-working-in-flutter)

Answer (score 54):

To modify the transition speed, you'll have to adjust the [PageRoute](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageRoute-class.html) transition duration (as already pointed out by @diegoveloper).

If you wanna keep the default transition, you can create a class implementing [MaterialPageRoute](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialPageRoute-class.html). If you already have your own transition or want to create one you can use the [PageRouteBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageRouteBuilder-class.html) to easily build your own. Simply adjust the `transitionDuration`.

Here's a small standalone example, using the `PageRouteBuilder`:

[image: Transition Demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Page1(),
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Page2'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  PageRouteBuilder(
                      transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                      pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => Page2())),
            ),
            Hero(tag: 'home', child: Icon(Icons.home))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Hero(
          tag: 'home',
          child: Icon(
            Icons.home,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: For anyone wondering how to slower the resize when the image gets smaller, use the `reverseTransitionDuration` property in PageRouteBuilder `reverseTransitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 2)`

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. A Possible Solution

I don't think the *only way* of achieving this is through changing the `PageRoute` transition duration. I think you could also achieve the same effect by using an `AnimationController` — this answer comes largely from lectures #149 and #150 of [Angela Yu's The Complete 2019 Flutter Development Bootcamp with Dart](https://www.udemy.com/course/flutter-bootcamp-with-dart/).

1. Turn your screen into a `StatefulWidget`.
2. If you're using only one animation, add `with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` to your state class.
3. Create a controller inside the state class.
4. If your animation is supposed to appear on the initialization of the screen, use the `controller` inside the `initState` method.

   - The controller has a property called `duration`, so you can change it to your liking.

#### 2. How It Would Look Like

In the end, everything should look a bit like this:

```dart
class _NewScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> 
  with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

  AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      vsync: this,
    );

    controller.forward();

    controller.addListener((){
      setState(() {
        
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ...
```

- `vsync` is a required (`@required`) parameter that takes the state (instance) object itself (usually).
- `addListener` and `setState` are there if you wish to use the value of the `controller` (`controller.value`) at some point in the future — for example, changing the height of the icon with something like `height: finalHeight * controller.value`.
- For the transition into this screen, I'm simply using a `FlatButton` with `Navigator.pushNamed`, nothing special.

#### 3. Some Additional Important Info

1. The `controller` will still be active even if you change screens later. So if you have a looping animation in the background, it's a good idea to *dispose* it when changing the screen, this way you don't waste phone resources with it anymore. This could be achieved with:

   ```dart
   @override
   void dispose() {
     controller.dispose();
     super.dispose();
   }
   ```
2. You could also customize *how* the animation is run, or how it is executed. One option is to use a `CurvedAnimation`.

   1. Declare `Animation animation;` right below your `controller`.
   2. Below your `controller`, inside `initState`, add:

      ```dart
      animation = CurvedAnimation( // the controller can't have upperBound > 1
        parent: controller,        // the controller you created
        curve: Curves.decelerate,
      );
      ```
3. Another useful way of animating in `Flutter` is by using *TweenAnimations*. For example, if you want to transition *between* colors, you could use `ColorTween` (below your `controller`, inside `initState`):

   ```dart
   animation = ColorTween(
     begin: Colors.red,
     end: Colors.blue,
   ).animate(controller);
   ```